# Initialize sparse static array

Tags: c++, arrays, static, initialization

I need to initialize a static array. Not all of the values are sequential.

Something like this works fine for a sequential array:

```
class Foo {

  public:

  static const char * name[];

}

const char * Foo::name[] = { "Sun", "Moon" };
```

How can I assign values at arbitrary positions in the array? I need to do something like this (pseudocode):

```
const char * Foo::name[] = { 67: "Sun", 68: "Moon" };
```

The array will never be bigger than 255; the indices come from byte values.

---

I found [part of a thread](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/133372-static-arrays-ellipsis-2.html) where someone gives an example of something similar to what I want, but I couldn't get anything like this to work.

```
type array[SIZE] = {[SIZE-4]=1, 2, 3, 4};
```

Comment: `[SIZE-4]=1` are called designated intializers and are only available in C and illegal in C++ (however, in gcc they offer it as an extension). However, non-trivial (i.e. your example) are not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one old-school approach:

```
class NameArray {
  public:
    NameArray()
    {
      array[67] = "Sun";
      array[68] = "Moon";
    }

    const char *operator[](size_t index) const
    {
      assert(index<256);
      return array[index];
    }


  private:
    const char * array[256];
};

class Foo {
  public:
    static NameArray name;
};

NameArray Foo::name;
```

By wrapping the array in a class, you can make sure it gets constructed with the values that you want.  You can also do bounds checking.

Comment: Should NameArray be a singleton if I'm going to do this?

Comment: @GGG: If by singleton you mean removing the ability to copy or assign, sure if that is what you want.

Comment: I mean, this doesn't really have the advantage of being static, I was thinking a singleton pattern could fix that, but it seems like overkill. I really just want a plain static sparse array. Is there no way to do that?

Comment: @GGG: I'm not sure what you mean.  It is still declared static in the Foo class.

Comment: Hmm, good point, I was thinking other things would need to instantiate NameArrays, but they would just look at Foo::name.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you to use `std::map<int, std::string>` (or `unordered_map` if you have C++11 support) instead of the array. You can then insert into this map with the code : `m[67] = "Sun"` and retrieve items using `std::string s = m[67];`.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to do it without importing any more libraries if possible.

Comment: @GGG: It is part of the C++ standard library..no additional libraries are required.

Comment: This will be different than the rest of the code. Why do you suggest using the std::strings instead of const char *? The code is written in a c-like way, encapsulated in classes.

Comment: @GGG: You can use use `const char*`, I suggested `std::string` as people generally forget the `const` part of the `char*` and use it as a non char* pointer with functions like `strcpy`. That will cause the program to crash.